# After double click over excel only format is getting applied over excel in npoi in C#

Tags: c#, excel, date, datetime, npoi

**I have one requirement that [image: requirement] where NPOI cell value is in format of "MM/dd/yy" and when user click on that specific cell, it should show complete value as shown into image.**

When i try to do manually, it works absolutely fine but when i apply through code. It does not work.

I am attaching sample code below for reference purpose. So you can guide me for possible solution. I will really appreciate your help and support.
Thanks in advance.

```
string value = "02/17/2017 10:10:10";
 DateTime datetime;
 SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat ("MM/dd/yy");
 DateTime dt = Convert.ToDateTime(value);
 var dateString = dateFormat.Format(dt, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
 if (DateTime.TryParseExact(dateString.ToString(), "MM/dd/yy",      CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out datetime))
 {
       cell.SetCellValue(datetime.Date);
 }
 else
 {
         cell.SetCellValue(value);
 }

//For styling
var dateTypecontentStyle = workbook.CreateCellStyle();
 dateTypecontentStyle.DataFormat = dataFormatCustom.GetFormat("MM/dd/yy");
 cell.CellStyle = dateTypecontentStyle;
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understood this correctly, are you trying to apply the date and time to a specific cell, and it isn't working ?

Comment: Yes, Requirement is when i click on excel cell, it should show date as well as time also. The raw value i am getting is complete date with time. I need to format that date and display as such that by default it should show only "MM/dd/yy" format but when user click it should show value in "MM/yy/dd hh:mm:ss" as shown in image above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the date format of the cell as `MM/dd/yy`, then set the full date in the cell. The cell should display the date as `MM/dd/yy` but display the full date when the cell is selected.

Try this code:

```
DateTime dateTest = DateTime.ParseExact("02/17/2017 10:10:10", "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"C:\temp\test.xlsx", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
{
    IWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
    ISheet sheet = workbook.CreateSheet("sheet");

    IRow row = sheet.CreateRow(0);

    ICell cell = row.CreateCell(0);
    ICellStyle cellStyle = workbook.CreateCellStyle();
    cellStyle.DataFormat = workbook.CreateDataFormat().GetFormat("MM/dd/yy"); 
    cell.CellStyle = cellStyle;
    cell.SetCellValue(dateTest);

    workbook.Write(fs);
}
```

Comment: Thanks @krlzlx.. I have also tried something similar and it worked for me.

Comment: You're welcome. Always glad to help. You can validate this answer if it resolved your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so from what I understand you need, this should do the trick:

Lets say you want to add the date and time to cell A1, here is how i went about it and it worked:

```
xl.range cellA1 = yourWorksheet.Cells[1,1];
cellA1.Formula = "=NOW()";
CellA1.Value = CellA1.Value;
CellA1.NumberFormat = "m/d/yyyy";
```

After this you should be left with your cell showing only the date, and inside the cell you should have the time aswell.
Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for answering my query but i have one query that are you talking in term of NPOI based excel formatting. Because i am using NPOI library for excel creating and formatting. Apart from above example, i have tried giving simple value and then putting style  like below but it didnt worked. It will greatly appreciated if you can update me interm of NPOI .                                                     dateTypecontentStyle.DataFormat = dataFormatCustom.GetFormat("MM/dd/yy");
                                cell.CellStyle = dateTypecontentStyle;

Comment: I've never used NPOI but I've lookd over some syntax fast, my best bet would to do something like :
1) Declaring the cell you need
2) Puting the formula in it
3) setting the cell value to equal that cell value
4) then going in with the syntaxt 
getFormat("m/d/yyyy");
I found info here : http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html
I think the answeres you need are found under  " Conditional Formatting" and "How to Create cells / How to create date cells"
I don't think i can be of any more use than this sadly but if i can think of something I will post it.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the data type of `cell.SetCellValue`.

- For *currency* dataformatter the data type will be *double* `cell.SetCellValue(double)`.
- For *date* it will be date,
- etc.

`cell.SetCellValue(String)` might cause your issue.